# Create a Program using Python: Program must count the number of words and count the number of letters in each word

Tags: python

The difficult part for me is the letter counting, It needs to be like this. 
ex: The candy is red (output needs to be: 3 5 2 3). Also the current code takes spaces into consideration which it should not.

This is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    phrase = input("Enter Your Sentence:")
    words = phrase.split()
    WordCount = len(words)
    LetterCount = len(phrase)
    print("Total Amount of Words in Sentence: %s" % WordCount)
    print("Total Amount of Letters in Sentence: %s" % LetterCount)
main()
```

example:

```
Enter your sentence: The sky is blue  
Total amount of words: 4 
Total amount of letters: 3 3 2 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def main():
    phrase = input("Enter Your Sentence: ")
    return [len(item) for item in phrase.split()]
```

---

```
>>> main()
Enter Your Sentence: The candy is red
[3, 5, 2, 3]
>>> main()
Enter Your Sentence: These are words
[5, 3, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, is it possible for you to give me the whole code, I am not getting the same results.

Comment: @BobStacy How so? What result are you getting?

Comment: @BobStacy that is the whole code. You can take the variables and parse them however you see fit in order to print them.

Comment: this is what is was getting until I ended the first main() and started another one, then it worked fine: http://imgur.com/Wx2jZga

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
        phrase = input("Enter Your Sentence:")
        words = phrase.split()
        WordCount = len(words)
        LetterCount = [len(word) for word in words]
        print("Total Amount of Words in Sentence:", WordCount)
        print("Total Amount of Letters in Sentence:", LetterCount)

main()
```

use an infinite while loop and break out of the loop when the user enters 'quit'

```
def main():
    while True:
        phrase = input("Enter Your Sentence or quit to exit: \n")
        if phrase.lower() == 'quit':
            break
        else:
            words = phrase.split()
            WordCount = len(words)
            LetterCount = [len(word) for word in words]
            print("Total Amount of Words in Sentence:", WordCount)
            print("Total Amount of Letters in Sentence:", LetterCount)

main()
```

Comment: Ok this works, thank you very much, but could you tell me why after the first input I get syntax errors?

Comment: i just copy-pasted my answer, didn't get any error what syntax error are you getting

Comment: That is what I am getting: http://imgur.com/RsngPHB  I am wondering is there any way to loop it without having to restart the program everytime

Comment: Next time Try to do a little google search, or post a new question instead of asking others to modify the original answers to your question :)

Comment: Ok im sorry, that is all I needed for this assignment but I was just personally wondering, I just figured since I had your attention I would ask you. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_input():
    phrase = input("Enter your sentence: ")
    return phrase

def word_count(phrase):
    list_of_words = phrase.split()
    count = 0
    for word in list_of_words:
        count += 1
    return count

def letter_count(phrase):
    list_of_words = phrase.split()
    count = 0
    letter_list = []
    for word in list_of_words:
        for char in word:
            count += 1
        letter_list += [count]
        count = 0
    letter_string = ' '.join(map(str, letter_list))
    return letter_string

def restart_program():
    restart_question = "Would you like to restart the program (y or n)? "
    restart_answer = str(input(restart_question.lower()))
    return restart_answer

def main():
    start_again = "y"
    while start_again == "y":
        phrase = user_input()
        number_words = word_count(phrase)
        letters = letter_count(phrase)

        print ("Total amount of words: ", number_words)
        print ("Total amount of letters: ", letters)
        print ()

        start_again = restart_program()

        print ()

    print ("Good Bye")

main()
```

Example Output:

```
Enter your sentence: The sky is blue
Total amount of words:  4
Total amount of letters:  3 3 2 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, its very interesting to see the different variations of code that can give you the same answer.

Comment: It's no problem. I modified the code to allow the user to restart the program without having to constantly re-run it.